# $\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx$ with $e^x=\cos(u)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Consider the integral
$$
I=\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx
$$
When using the substitution $e^x=\sin(u)$, I get $I=\arcsin(e^x)+C$. However, when using $e^x=\cos(u)$, I get $du/dx=-e^x/\sin(u)$ and thus
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx&=\int \frac{\cos (u)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(u)}}\frac{dx}{du}du\\
&=-\int \frac{\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}\frac{\sin(u)}{e^x}\,du\\
&=-\int 1 \,du=-u+C=-\arccos(e^x)+C.
\end{align}
$$
What am I missing?

Comment: What is it that makes you think either answer is wrong?

Comment: $e^{x} = cos(u)$ is not a valid substitution, since $e^{x}$ might be greater than 1. Same deal for $e^{x} = \sin(u)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I believe the first answer is right, I feel the second substitution might be invalid, but why? Besides, $\arcsin(e^x)+\arccos(e^x)=\pi/2$. Are they the same up to a constant? Or is something wrong?

Comment: Both answers are right, but the method itself is wrong, since it only guarantees your integral is valid in the interval [-1,1]. But with an different choice of subsitution, you can easily show it holds everywhere.

Comment: Actually, maybe wrong is a strong word, since it's technically possible if you allow complex $u$, but then you start to get into an area I have no understanding off. Over the reals (which i assume is where we are doing this), the subsitution you made is very wacky

Comment: The two answers are ok, note that the answers correspond to the same class of functions up to a constant. The $C$ in $\arcsin\exp x+C$ is not "the same $C$" as in "the other" answer.

Comment: mhm, that's what I have been saying, I only questioned the u-sub. I have the plots in a answer below, they are, in fact equivalent

Comment: @Almeida The method is not wrong. If you are worried about the function being defined in the set of real numbers, then actually, this substitution works just fine. Look at the original function to observe the permissible domain. In case you are ready to define the function in the domain of complex numbers, look at the complex definitions of sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Im an idiot. You're absolutely right @ShubhavJain. Sorry! I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

The answers in question are both correct (the +C exists for a reason). Plot both graphs and you will see they are just offsets of each other (hence the constant)[image]

The method to get to the answers, however, is questionable. $e^{x} = \sin(u)$ is impossible whenever $x>0$, as it will be outside sines range. Interestingly enough, it still arrives at the right answer.

Now, to actually solve this, the proper way would be to consider $u=e^{x}$, meaking $du = e^{x}dx$, and:

$\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx = \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}}du = \sin^{-1}(u) +C = \sin^{-1}(e^{x})+C$

**EDIT**
The substitution is fine, as the denominator of the function guarantees that $x<0$, meaning the sub works. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you! Is there a stronger argument as to why the substitution is invalid? Giving the correct answer is suspicious, but I wonder what the formalism should be.

Comment: @samwolfe i stand corrected, it is not wrong, since $x>0$ isn't allowed anyways because of the denominator. I'll edit my answer in a moment